# What is the meaning behind this definition of a set?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

$$\{A: A\subseteq\{1,2,\ldots,n\}\land \{7\}\subseteq A\land\{3,5\}\cap A=\varnothing\}$$

By looking the " $\{7\}\subseteq A\land\{3,5\}\cap A=\varnothing$ " I see that the set $\{7\}$ is a subset of the empty set which is confusing me ,and by looking at the "$A\subseteq\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$" I see that $A$ is a subset of the natural numbers, so after looking at both sides I said that $A$ is a subset of the natural numbers and used logical and on the empty set and I got the empty set.

can you someone guide me through this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that we take the subsets $A$ of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ such that:

1. $\{7\}\subseteq A$, which means that $7\in A$, **and**
2. $A\cap\{3,5\}=\varnothing$, which means that neither $3$ nor $5$ are in $A$.

So it is true that $7\in A$, while $3\notin A$ and $5\notin A$. Your confusion arises by reading "through" the conjunction, rather than separating the properties.

Since $n$ is not quantified, there are two options here: either the meaning is that $n$ was fixed before hand, or that we implicitly take all bounded subsets of $\Bbb N$ which satisfy these two conditions. This depends on the context, but the first interpretation is the more likely one.

Comment: That is correct. In which case the entire set is empty. Because there is no subset of $\{1,\ldots,6\}$ which has $7$ as an element.

Comment: No. Not every subset of $\{1,2,4,6,7\}$ will be there. Only those where $7$ is an element. You could, however, present that as taking every subset of $\{1,2,4,6\}$ and adding $7$ to it.

Comment: @user3133165 For $n=7$, you can see all of the elements of your set in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In writing, it is the set of all subsets of $\mathbb N$ that contain as their subset the set $\{7\}$ and have a empty intersection with the set $\{3,5\}$.

In other words, it is the set of all subsets of $\{1,2,\dots, n\}$ that contain $7$ do not contain either $3$ or $5$.

---

For example, if $n=7$, then the set equals

$$\{\{7\}, \\\{1,7\},\{2,7\},\{4,7\}\{6,7\},\\\{1,2,7\} \{1,4,7\}, \{1,6,7\}, \{2,4,7\}, \{2,6,7\}, \{4,6,7\}, \\
\{1,2,4,7\}, \{1,2,6,7\}, \{1,4,6,7\}, \{2,4,6,7\},\\
\{1,2,4,6,7\}\}$$

Comment: @user3133165 Now, the set does not contain $7$. It contains $\{\7\}$. The first condition says $A\subset\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$ and tells you that the *elements* of your set must *themselves* be sets of integers.